# Should I draw directly on a CCLayer or a CCSprite?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, ccsprite

Now I am a little confused in my cocos2d-x cpp project. I want to draw lines with user's finger touch. Following the screenshot of a CCScene:

[image]

In the screen, there are two squares. I want show an animation in the first square and let the second one draw lines with user touch.

Now these two squares are `CCSprite`. And I can draw dots in the second one on the `CCLayer`. But I am little confused that I should draw lines on the `Sprite` or on the `Layer`.

Or are there other ways to organize the code?

Comment: U added a sprite on CCLayer. IF you add it on CCLayer it also works

Comment: 1)How this sentanse is revelant to question? "I want show an animation in the first square"  +  2) How are you drawing dots in the second square ?

Answer (score 1):

well, ask yourself, do the lines only pertain to the squares? If so, why not add the lines as a child of the square and then setting the position to where you want it. Since the lines are children of square positioning starts relative to the squares position.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to draw lines with user's finger touch. Following the
>   screenshot of a CCScene

I had a same project in cocos2dx. for drawing something like this you can use `CCRenderTexture`. RenderTexture work like a paiting canvas. you put a sprite ( imagine it as a painting brush) on somewhere on RenderTexture and call `sprite->visit()`. If you this `visit()` on `CCTouchMoved()` you can draw on Render Texture as player finger move.

If you are more interseted in more detail you can check this example:

```
void ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    RenderTexure->begin();
    brush->setVisible(true); // brush is a simple sprite
}
void PaintingScene::ccTouchesMoved(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    CCPoint currentTouch = touch->getLocation();
    brush->setPosition(currentTouch);
    brush->visit();
}
void ccTouchesEnded(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    brush->setVisible(false);
    RenderTexure->end();
}
```